# hive-hbase integration issue

Tags: hive, hbase

I want to create a table in hive like below but getting error

```html
hive (default)> CREATE TABLE hbase_table_1(key int, value1 string, value2 int, value3 int) 
          > STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
          > WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
          > "hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,a:b,a:c,d:e"
          > );
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HTableDescriptor.addFamily(Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/HColumnDescriptor;)V
```

I have configured .hiverc file as below. Am I missing any more jars?

```html
hduser@ubuntu:/usr/lib/hive/conf$ cat .hiverc
SET hive.cli.print.header=true;
SET hive.cli.print.current.db=true;
SET hive.auto.convert.join=true;
add JAR /usr/lib/hive/lib/zookeeper-3.4.6.jar;
add JAR /usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-hbase-handler-1.2.0.jar;
add JAR /usr/lib/hive/lib/guava-14.0.1.jar;
add JAR /usr/lib/hive/auxlib/hadoop-common-2.7.0.jar;
add JAR /usr/lib/hive/auxlib/high-scale-lib-1.1.1.jar;
add JAR /usr/lib/hive/lib/hive-serde-1.2.0.jar;
add JAR /usr/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-annotations-1.1.1.jar;
add JAR /usr/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-it-1.1.1.jar;
add JAR /usr/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-prefix-tree-1.1.1.jar;
add JAR /usr/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-rest-1.1.1.jar;
add JAR /usr/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-server-1.1.1.jar;
add JAR /usr/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-procedure-1.1.1.jar;
add JAR /usr/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-shell-1.1.1.jar;
add JAR /usr/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-thrift-1.1.1.jar;
add JAR /usr/lib/hbase/lib/commons-beanutils-1.7.0.jar;
add JAR /usr/lib/hbase/lib/commons-beanutils-core-1.8.0.jar;
add JAR /usr/lib/hbase/lib/commons-cli-1.2.jar;
add JAR /usr/lib/hbase/lib/commons-codec-1.9.jar;
add JAR /usr/lib/hbase/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar;
add JAR /usr/lib/hbase/lib/commons-compress-1.4.1.jar;
add JAR /usr/lib/hbase/lib/commons-digester-1.8.jar;
add JAR /usr/lib/hbase/lib/commons-el-1.0.jar;
add JAR /usr/lib/hbase/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar;
add JAR /usr/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-protocol-1.1.1.jar;
add JAR /usr/lib/hbase/lib/htrace-core-3.1.0-incubating.jar;
add JAR /usr/lib/hbase/lib/commons-configuration-1.6.jar;
add JAR /usr/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-common-1.1.1.jar;
add JAR /usr/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-client-1.1.1.jar;
add JAR /usr/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-hadoop2-compat-1.1.1.jar;
add JAR /usr/lib/hbase/lib/hbase-hadoop-compat-1.1.1.jar;
add JAR /usr/local/src/spark/lib/spark-assembly-1.3.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar;
```

Comment: your syntax is missing a line - TBLPROPERTIES("hbase.table.name" = "some_existing_table");

Comment: Actually if you don't specify any table name then it consider hive table name as hbase table name. `hive (default)> CREATE TABLE hbase_table_1(key int, value string)
              > STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
              > WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,cf1:val")
              > TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "xyz");
FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask. org.apache.hadoop.hbase.HTableDescriptor.addFamily(Lorg/apache/hadoop/hbase/HColumnDescriptor;)V
` With tablename I am getting error